# Decomposition of function on annulus

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a problem in understanding a part of proof for Laurent decomposition:

> Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on an annulus $\mathcal{A} := \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : r < |z| < R\}$. Then, it can be decomposed in $f(z) := g(z) + h(\frac{1}{z})$, where $g:D_R(0) \to \mathbb{C}$ and $h:D_{\frac{1}{r}}(0) \to \mathbb{C}$ where $g$ and $h$ are holomorphic.

Ok. So I have a problem with demonstration for uniqueness for this function $f$.

Let $f(z) = g_1(z) + h_1(\frac{1}{z}) = g_2(z) + h_2(\frac{1}{z}) \iff (g_1 - g_2)(z) + (h_1 - h_2)(z) \equiv 0 $. So it is sufficient to prove that, if $g(z) + h(\frac{1}{z}) \equiv 0 \implies g \equiv h \equiv 0$, where $g\in O(D_R(0)), h \in O(D_{\frac{1}{r}}(0))$.

So, $g(z) = -h(\frac{1}{z}) \forall z \in \mathcal{A}$.
Let $F:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}, F(z)= \begin{cases}
        g(z) & \text{if } z \in D_r(0)\\
        g(z) = - h(\frac{1}{z})& \text{if } z \in \overline{\mathcal{A}}\\
-h(\frac{1}{z}) & \text{if } z \in \mathbb{C} - \overline{D_R(0)}
    \end{cases}$

$F$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$.

**But here in proof it says that
$\lim_{z\to\infty}F(z)=-h(0) \in \mathbb{C} \implies F$ is bounded.**

My question is why if $F$ is holomorphic at $\infty \implies F$ is bounded?

Comment: Every continuous function in the plane, which tends to $0$ when $|z|\to\infty,$ is bounded. Apply this to $F(z)+h(0).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As

$$\lim_{\lvert z\rvert\to\infty}F(z)=-h(0),$$

we can find a $\rho>0$ such that

$$\lvert F(z)+h(0)\rvert\leq1$$

whenever $\lvert z\rvert\geq\rho$. In particular, if we set $M=1+\lvert h(0)\rvert$, then

$$\lvert F(z)\rvert\leq\lvert F(z)+h(0)\rvert+\lvert h(0)\rvert\leq M$$

for all $\lvert z\rvert\geq\rho$. But now as $F$ is holomorphic, it is continuous on the disk $\lvert z\rvert\leq\rho$, and as this disk is compact, the continuous function $\lvert F\rvert$ attains a maximum there. Now set

$$\alpha=\max\left\{M,\max_{\lvert z\rvert\leq\rho}\lvert F(z)\rvert\right\}.$$

Then $\lvert F(z)\rvert\leq\alpha$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$, as if $\lvert z\rvert\leq\rho$, then

$$\lvert F(z)\rvert\leq\max_{\lvert z\rvert\leq\rho}\lvert F(z)\rvert\leq \alpha,$$

and if $\lvert z\rvert\geq\rho$, then

$$\lvert F(z)\rvert\leq M\leq\alpha.$$

Thus $F$ is bounded.